# Conditionally load class in the comment section of the post page

Tags: php, comments, css

I want to be able to conditionally load a class containing the word 'AUTHOR' in the comments section, next to the name of the person who was the author of the post. I know it has something to do with class bypostauthor, what I've got so far is:

```
<?php if $class == 'bypostauthor' ?>
    <div class="author">AUTHOR</div> 
<? endif; ?>
```

More info:

In comment section of my wordpress post page, the class .bypostauthor exists whenever a the author of post page comments on there post page, giving this for one of the comments in the comment section ->

I'm trying to accomplish having the word 'AUTHOR' next to the author of post name whenever they comment on there page. Considering bypostauthor class appears whenever page author post a comment on his page I tried to use the following code to make a div class conditionally appear whenever the post author comments ->

```
<li <?php comment_class('clearfix'); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">

    <div class="comment-block" id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="comment-inside-block">
        <div class="comment-info">  
            <div class="comment-author vcard clearfix">

                <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, 32 ); ?>

                <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                    <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', 'playne'), get_comment_author_link()) ?><?php if $class == 'bypostauthor' ?>
    <div class="author">AUTHOR</div> 
<? endif; ?>

                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <a class="comment-time" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>">  <?php echo themeblvd_time_ago_1(); ?>   </a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)', 'playne'),'  ','') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-text">
            <?php comment_text() ?>
            <p class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
            <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'playne') ?></em>
        <?php endif; ?>    

    </div>
```

">
            
              
                

                    comment_author_email, 32 ); ?>

```
                <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                    <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', 'playne'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>

                    <?php echo author_tag(); ?>

                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <a class="comment-time" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>">  <?php echo themeblvd_time_ago_1(); ?>   </a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)', 'playne'),'  ','') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-text">
            <?php comment_text() ?>
            <p class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Tried something based on answer ->

```
function author_tag() {
    $classes = get_comment_class();
    if(in_array('bypostauthor',$classes)) {
        $output = <div class="author-tag"><p>AUTHOR</p></div>;
    } else {
        $output = <div class="author-tag"><p>NOT AUTHOR</p></div>;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there with your first piece of code. For this to completely work, you'll need to get a list of the comment classes and check your class against that list. If your class exists in that returned list, you can something, if not, do something else

Use [`get_comment_class()`](http://wpseek.com/?p=detail&s=get_comment_class) to retrieve that list. Here is an example

```
$classes = get_comment_class();
if(in_array('bypostauthor',$classes)) {
    // do something for bypostauthor class
} else {
    // do something else if bypostauthor class don't exist
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Your problem is pure syntax. Your HTML needs to be between single quotes (`'`), otherwise it is read as php, which is invalid php, caussing the syntax error. Check my example below

```
function author_tag() {
    $classes = get_comment_class();
    if(in_array('bypostauthor',$classes)) {
        $output = '<div class="author-tag"><p>AUTHOR</p></div>';
    } else {
        $output = '<div class="author-tag"><p>NOT AUTHOR</p></div>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I would advice you to get a good syntax highligher, this will help you a lot with invalid syntaxes

Comment: possibly use `get_comment_class()`

Comment: @Micheal yes, thanks for that. Blue Monday. Will update my answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ok, I'm really new to php but my attempt at it looks like this -> 'code'$classes = get_body_class();
      if(in_array('bypostauthor',$classes)) {
          <div class="author-tag"><p>AUTHOR</p></div>
      } else {
          <div class="not-author-tag"><p>NOT AUTHOR</p></div>
      }

Comment: Ok, ya, you have a problem with syntax here

Comment: @PieterGoosen I updated the main post with the new code I used, I get the error -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/trentaug/public_html/wp-content/themes/Typer/functions.php on line 10

Comment: Please see my updated code